# Python import scope issue

Tags: python

I'm trying to do some script reuse for some python build scripts. An abbreviated version of my "reusable" part looks like (_build.py):

```
Sources = []
Sources += glob('*.c')
Sources += glob('../FreeRTOS/*.c')
...
def addSources(directory, *rest):
  for each in rest:
    Sources += ['../'+directory+'/'+each+'.c']

def addSharedSources(*args):
  addSources('Shared', *args)
```

Then in the customized part, I have something like (build.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from _build import *
...
#Additional source files from ../Shared, FreeRTOS and *.c are already in
addSharedSources('ccpwrite', 'discovery', 'radioToo', 'telemetry', 'utility')
```

Unfortunately, when I try to run build.py, I get a traceback that looks like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./build.py", line 8, in <module>
 addSharedSources('ccpwrite', 'discovery', 'radioToo', 'telemetry', 'utility')
File "/Users/travisg/Projects/treetoo/Twig/_build.py", line 49, in addSharedSources
 addSources('Shared', *args)
File "/Users/travisg/Projects/treetoo/Twig/_build.py", line 46, in addSources
 Sources += ['../'+directory+'/'+each+'.c']
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Sources' referenced before assignment
```

So even though I did the wildcard import, it would appear that when the import function is called, it's not referencing my "global" variable imported from the original. Is there a way to make it work? I toyed around with `global`, but that didn't seem to do what I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the import. You'll have the same problem if you run `_build.py` directly. The problem is that the function `addSources` is modifying the global `Sources` without declaring it global. Insert a `global` declaration in the `addSources` function, and all should be well.

Explanation: It is very easy to write this kind of code by mistake. So python allows you to *read* a global variable without declaring it global, but not to modify it.

Comment: Ah thank you. I thought I had done that. Indeed I had tried `global Sources += [...]`. But that doesn't work, you have to do the `global Sources` as a separate statement.

Comment: Can you explain why Sources.append( val ) would work?  At least, append is working for me.

Comment: I guess I should have written "python does not allow you to _assign_ to a global variable without declaring it global". Basically, all the interpreter sees is that you're calling a method; and that's allowed. It so happens that `append()` modifies the variable, but that's beyond the scope of the interpreter's safety check (and could change at runtime, if you override the method etc.)